# How can I make ten <a> links appear as two rows of five?

Tags: css

I have the following:

```
<div id='hdr_thm'>
    <div>
        <a style="background-color: #FFFFFF;" href="#" data-style="arctic" title="Arctic"></a>
        <a style="background-color: #F2F2F2;" href="#" data-style="aristo" title="Aristo"></a>
        <a style="background-color: #E6E6E6;" href="#" data-style="black-tie" title="Black Tie"></a>
        <a style="background-color: #CCCCCC;" href="#" data-style="blitzer" title="Blitzer"></a>
        <a style="background-color: #808080;" href="#" data-style="cobalt" title="Cobalt"></a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a style="background-color: #FCEE21;" href="#" data-style="flick" title="Flick"></a>
        <a style="background-color: #D9E021;" href="#" data-style="hot-sneaks" title="Hot Sneaks"></a>
        <a style="background-color: #8CC63F;" href="#" data-style="humanity" title="Humanity"></a>
        <a style="background-color: #009245;" href="#" data-style="le-frog" title="Le Frog"></a>
        <a style="background-color: #006837;" href="#" data-style="midnight" title="Midnight"></a>
    </div>

... etc

</div>

#hdr_thm {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 15px;
    z-index: 20;
}

#hdr_thm a {
    border: 1px solid #050505;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 10px;
}
```

What I would like to do is to have two rows here. Each row with five `<a>` elements.  But the problem 
for me is how can I get the rows to wrap around so that the second five squares appear below
the first five.

Comment: Sounds like you need a [line break](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add a clear:left to the div's:

```
#hdr_thm div {
    clear:left;
}
```

Your original code worked on chrome. With the above code it also works on IE.

Comment: Addionally: You could modify his selector like this: `#hdr_thm > div` if inside of the DIVs could contain further DIVs (created by js for example).

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't work in IE7. That's why I edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

Alternativley you could use

```
display: inline-block;
```

instead of

```
display: block;
float: left;
```

*Note: Internet Explorer 6 doesn't support "inline-block" as value, so there you can use simple "inline", which got the same behavior like inline-block in later versions or other browsers. Of course, just if you want to support it.*

Answer (score -2):

If you want each of the 5 links in the two rows to line up exactly, using a table might actually be the best solution in this case.

Otherwise, make sure the two inner div's are relatively positioned to each other, which should resolve your issue.

Comment: Tables are never the best solution, except for tables!